# Arabic Data Is Exported As?

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2012

I am trying to import Arabic data from SQL Server 2012 (DB collation `Arabic_CI_AS` and the columns are `varchar`) to Excel using external data sources connections.

Data is imported to Excel as question marks (???)

Comment: Is it a CSV file that you're exporting to? If so, I suspect that you're not getting Unicode encoding in your export. On a side note, I'm surprised that your columns are of type `varchar`. I expect Arabic characters requires `nvarchar`.

Comment: not a CSV file, i'm importing from SQL to Excel direct using Excel External data wizard. Arabic is stored in Varchar because the DB collation is Arabic_BIN

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry, you did specify that in the question. This is a long shot, but presumably your language settings are set correctly in Excel?